# Using an address with Venue Search

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to use a full address with venue search and not having much luck.

Passing the string 'brooklyn NY 11201' via the near param returns a list of venues in the 11201 area code.

Passing the string '22 Jay St, Brooklyn NY 11201' via the near param returns a failed geocode error.

The near, client_id, and client_secret params are the only params I am passing. Is there something else that I need to get the foursquare geocoder to work, or does it just not accept specific addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Foursquare geocoder doesn't support the conversion of fine street addresses very well. City- or zip code-level granularity will be your best bet.